# How to make plugin not cacheable in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I write a plugin for check IP address and make a function `aroundDispatch()`.

```
Let me clear more this is given below function.
This given one is cached.
    $this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress()

public function aroundDispatch(
    \Magento\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
) {
    $scopeStores    = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES;
    $currentStoreId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    if (!$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag('amgeoipredirect/general/enable', $scopeStores, $currentStoreId)
        || $this->isNeedToProceed($request)
    ) {
        return $proceed($request);
    }

    $this->applyLogic($request);

    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

    $currentStoreId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();

    if ($this->scopeConfig->getValue('amgeoipredirect/general/enable', $scopeStores, $currentStoreId)
        && $this->redirectAllowed
    ) {
        $location = $this->geolocation->locate($this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress());
        $country  = $location->getCountry();
        $session = $this->customerSession;
        $countRedirectStore    = 0;
        $countRedirectCurrency = 0;
        $countRedirectUrl      = 0;
```

Problem is IP is not changing, it is only changed when cache is fllush out.

How to stop caching this plugin file
Anyone have any idea about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is use Ajax for get dynamically data.Another solution is Placeholder same as Hole punching in magento1.
    Read article

```
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html
```

Comment: i want these two things $this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress()
and country according to this ip dynamically.

Comment: ok,so make a controller and in this controller get all your data,ip,address whatever and call this controller via ajax and return result data.

Comment: How to get data in plugin file. i make a controller and set return value. But how to get in plugin file.

Comment: You can make a custom controller and call it from phtml file where you want the data and capture data dynamically from controller in phtml file.

Comment: I know but i want data in plugin file for aroundDispatch function. How can i do that